# Assignment Java Questions

Tags: java, assert, pmd

I have a question regarding this programming code I get the following error message

```
assertTrue(true);
```

> Error [PMD]:  This assertion uses only values known at compile time,
>   so it cannot test any useful behavior exhibited by your code at
>   run-time.

Do you know what I can do to fix this code so it does not show it again

Comment: You are asserting that true is true. i.e. your test does nothing and is pointless. Remove the warning by removing the pointless assertion

Comment: Remove the statement?

Comment: Yes, `true` will be true in any case.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly what the context is for your code, but `true` is always true, and `assertTrue`'s job is to check if something is true.

Since your asserting that true is true, you are not doing anything practical and the test is pointless.  PMD is reporting to you that your test does nothing. (i.e. It is technically valid Java code, just pointless code).

Presumably, you can just remove that line.  If this is in a test, it should be replaced with a test that can actually potentially be true or false.